# Отличие заголовочных файлов и библиотечных в С++?

Tags: c++

КАкие отличия в заголовочных и библиотечных файлах в С++?

Comment: Вопрос не понятен.

Comment: А что такое «библиотечный файл»?

Comment: видимо библиотечные файлы, это lib/a файлы.

Answer (score 2):

Вкратце...

Самое простое и очевидное - заголовочный файл - это обычный текстовый файл, а библиотечный - это набор бинарного скомпилированного объектного кода.

Заголовочный файл содержит, как правило, все объявления - типов, функций, шаблонов и т.п. - всего, что должно быть видно из нескольких единиц трансляции, чтоб не писать этот все в каждом .cpp-файле.

Библиотека содержит уже готовый скомпилированный код, который опять же можно подключать в разные проекты, чтобы не компилировать его заново.

Так что заголовочный файл читает и обрабатывает компилятор при компиляции кода в объектный, а библиотекой занимается уже линковщик.

Comment: А как же header-only библиотеки?

Comment: @alexolut Вряд ли на вопрос ребенка "почему Земля кружится вокруг Солнца" имеет смысл рассказывать общую теорию относительности...

Comment: Вы видимо забываете, что ответ не только для ТС, а и для многих других людей, кто попадет позже на эту страницу.

Comment: @alexolut В таком случае все ответы должны быть одинаковы - просто цитирование стандарта :) Вы, видимо, не учитываете, что человек, имеющий хотя бы малейшее представление о заголовочных файлах и библиотеках, не будет искать ответ на этот вопрос. И еще - ведь мой ответ совершенно не лишает Вас права написать хороший, абсолютно полный, со всеми нюансами ответ! P.S. Когда будете писать свой ответ - не забудьте, что формально стандартные заголовочные файлы не обязаны быть текстовыми и файлами вообще. И о предкомпилированных заголовках. И о... впрочем, оставим кое-что и для мелочных придирок :)

Comment: я не могу писать ответ пока автор не прояснил вопрос. Собирать репу на догадках - не мой метод. Поэтому я проголосовал за закрытие вопроса для прояснения его сути.

Comment: @alexolut Ваше право иметь свой взгляд на вещи и поступать соответственно им. Надеюсь, Ваше право не подразумевает отсутствия такого же права у других? :)